# How to accept bank details from users of different countries in Stripe for payout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe payout to customers, but the problem I am facing is that as the app users are global, and according to Stripe, different countries require different bank detail information. Please refer to the [Stripe documentation for Bank account formats by country](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts-bank-accounts#formats).

Is there any way I can integrate one page for all users for every country when inserting bank details or do I need to make multiple pages based on the country?

app.js

```
const bankAccount = await stripe.customers.createSource('cus_xxx', {
  bank_account: {
    object: "bank_account", 
    account_holder_name: "Foo Bar", 
    account_holder_type: "individual",  
    account_number: "000123456789", 
    routing_number: "110000000", 
    country: "US", 
    currency: "usd",
  }
});
```

Comment: The question seems to be broad and vague, so apologies if this isn't the type of suggestion that you're looking for. Could you have a country drop-down selector that drives what fields are displayed based on the requirements in the document that you referenced?

Comment: yes was wondering if there is a stripe page which we can connect to to accept bank details based on the country or else I will have to make this page with 194 countries and different bank details

Comment: Sorry for not spotting this earlier, but you're also mixing up some Stripe concepts. You won't make Payouts to Customers, Customer objects represent customers of your products/service. Payouts represent Stripe moving funds from your available Stripe balance to your associated External Account (bank or card). Can you clarify what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to accept payments from your customer's bank accounts, or are you trying to setup Connected Accounts for a Stripe Connect scenario?